# How to specify different local maven repositories for different projects in their pom files?

Tags: maven

I have one .m2 repository. I have 2 projects. JavaProject and HibernateProject. I want them to reference different .m2 repositories. How is this done?

Comment: Why? What is the reason? What do you like to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify the local repository location in your POM file. If you were able to, it would break Maven: the whole point is to be able to distribute your POM file to other people and have the code just work. If the POM file contains a reference to `~seanmc/localrepos/hibernateproject` then it's not going to work on my machine.

The place where you specify the local repository is in your `settings.xml`. Typically you have one global settings and one user settings. You can pass the `-s` flag to Maven to specify a settings file to use. So you could make a settings file for each project. Inside the settings file ([reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)) you'll want a `<localRepository>` tag with the path to the local Maven repository you want to use.

Be aware, though, that doing this is contrary to Maven's design. Probably, you have a bug in your architecture or your thinking.